# Merging two XML files, comments only

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, comments

There is an XML file that is being modified regularly by external system, but has no comments. I am keeping a copy of that file and adding comments as appropriate. I need to refresh my copy of that file with updated data, but keep the comments. Sample files follow.

Master Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a>2</a>
<c>3</c>
<d>5</d>
</root>
```

Comments File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a>1</a>
<b>8<!--Comment for b-->
</b>
<c>3<!--Comment for c-->
</c>
</root>
```

Expected Result (Merged Files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a>2</a>
<c>3<!--Comment for c-->
</c>
<d>5</d>
</root>
```

Comment: What language/platform would you like? Do you care where in the DOM tree the comments are inserted?

Comment: No preference really, although I am used on XML Spy. The comments have to be at exactly the same place as in the source file. If specific place does not exist, ignore the comment or report somehow.